# Do you know any free private chat tools or code for web site?

Tags: asp.net, chat

I have online dating service. Premium user see a profile on site. profile is online. user want to make a private chat whit he/she. then open a window like gtalk or facebook and user chat with he/she.

do you know any free tools/widget/code for this?
technology:asp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest :

- [- LCSK (LiveChat Starter
  Kit)](http://livechatstarterkit.codeplex.com/)
- [- tChat](http://tchat.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you can use [Google Talk widget](http://googletalk.blogspot.com/2008/02/google-talk-chatback.html).

Comment: gtalk work in above scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can find various tools on

[codeplex](http://www.codeplex.com/site/search?query=chat)